# Determining the event when the iOS App is in Closed State to send a LocalNotification on seeing a Beacon

Tags: ios, ios7, lifecycle, ibeacon, ios7.1

I'm Developing a App using a iBeacon functionality. I want to fire an event when the App is in background & when it is closed. These have different Alert messages. I was able to determine when the App goes to Background. But was finding it difficult when the App gets closed.

I set a checkpoint for the App when it is in background state. But how should we find if the App is closed completely.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

i don't know what exactly you want but you can check you app state by following line of code

```
UIApplicationState state = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState];
```

UIApplicationStateBackground when application is in background

UIApplicationStateInactive when app is not in background

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `UIApplicationDelegate`'s `- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application` method. Seems like what you need. It will be called before application is terminated (for example as a result of user removing it from the list of running apps).

Comment: when I set a variable to false in this method then it doesn't the change the variable to false.

Comment: if you are not saving this variable it will always false.

Comment: @Pandey_Laxman I set the variable as FALSE in the Application life cycle method. -(void)applicationWillTerminate. Instead it remains as TRUE.

Comment: Can you provide more details on how you set the variable and how/where you check it again? Basically, `applicationWillTerminate` is the last method being invoked before application is terminated, so for your variable to remain at `FALSE` you must persist it somehow (e.g. write to a file).